# Mysql Insert Collation Issue

Tags: mysql, collation

When i try to insert to database. Turkish characters are changing

For Exp.

```
ı -> i ğ - > g
```

I have changed collation to utf_turkish_ci but it is not working. What am i suppose to do?

Answer (score 1):

Update your column collation to `utf8_general_ci` and charset to `utf8`

```
ALTER TABLE yourTable
  CHANGE changeCol changeCol VARCHAR(100) CHARSET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NULL ;
```

[Demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ncCB8H9emacfqjyRrDxCXA/0) works with both `utf8_turkish_ci` and `utf8_general_ci`

Comment: still not working. I think my sql version is causing this  5.1.73

Comment: found it. I've addet this " Charset=utf8 " in connection string. and it works! Thank you for your helps

Comment: @PsyGnosis - Please put on your calendar to upgrade from 5.1 -> 5.5 -> 5.6 -> 5.7 -- you are very far behind.  (No, I don't think 5.1 has any issues with Turkish and utf8.)